# Use app.delete [express.js] to delete collections in a mongo database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Questions 1:

I wonder what the purpose of app.delete.

I have this dinamically button for delete collections in my database:

```
<a class="destroy" href="delete/839894898293"> Delete </a>
```

839894898293 = _ID (I'm using EJS to populate this button.

And i have this app.get route to find the collection by id and remove it:

```
app.get('/delete/:id', function(req, res) {
 var id = req.param("id");

        MyModel.remove({
            _id: id 
        }, function(err){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            else {
                res.send("Removed");
            }
        });
}
```

This is working 100%, i can use.. but, why app.delete exists?? Am i doing something wrong??? Can i use the app.delete???

Questions 2:

I'm using the following code to confirm the deletate:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.destroy').click(function() {
        confirm("Are you sure?");
    });
});
```

When i click, the confirm appears, but if I cancel, the collection will be deleted anyway. Why? How can i fix??

Comment: The difference is semantic - `DELETE /1234` is clearer (and better adheres to the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)) than `GET /delete/1234` - you're deleting a resource, not fetching it.

Comment: but how tricker the app.delete in the html??

Comment: It should be trivial - tell your AJAX library to issue a `DELETE`, not a `GET` request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question 1:

`app.delete` is for the `DELETE` HTTP verb. `app.get` is for making a `GET` request; `app.delete` is for a `DELETE` one.

For question 2:

```
$('.destroy').click(function() {
    confirm("Are you sure?");
});
```

You're running `confirm` and then dropping the result. You need to `return` the result to be able to cancel it:

```
$('.destroy').click(function() {
    return confirm("Are you sure?");
});
```

Comment: if i use app.delete, this will show in the browser: Cannot GET /delete/54aac376ce133a95093de1ad .. how tricker the delete method @Scimonster??

Comment: Could you first clarify what `.destroy` is in the HTML, and how your current request to `/delete/...` is made?

Comment: is working! :).. i'm using a ajax to send a delete http request.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use app.delete for this, as opposed to app.get. This is because app.get will respond to a GET request to your resource, ie, an HTTP request with method type of GET. This is typically used to fetch information from a web server, and typically should not have any side effects (ie, affect your data). This is because web crawlers will typically hit all GET endpoints. If a google crawler was to hit your page, see the link, and follow it, would you really want Google to accidentally delete your data? Probably not.

You can find some more information regarding HTTP methods [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Comment: understood.. but, how can i fix the code to work with app.delete?? How tricker the delete method in the html??

Comment: if i use app.delete, this will show in the browser: Cannot GET /delete/54aac376ce133a95093de1ad

Answer (score 0):

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', function(req, res) {
var id = req.param("id");
    MyModel.remove({
        _id: id 
    }, function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else {
           return res.send("Removed");
        }
    });
});
```

Then for the button, @scimonster clarified it for you.
For it to also work properly 
the endpoint `/delete/:id` needs to point to the right item, trim every white space in the url coming from the broweser.